# VMWare out of memory when increasing ram to VM's

Tags: esxi

New to VMware, thanks for any and all help.

I created 3 VM's on a host, and didn't realize I goofed on memory allocation. I did: VM1 - 4GB VM2 - 4GB VM3 - 8GB

When that should have been double.

Now when I try to increase that under VM properties, I get a system out memory error when restarting the machine.

Is there a good solution to my dilemma?

vmware esxi

Comment: Are you trying to run all three VM at the sametime?

Comment: You'll probably need more than 4 GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM does the host have? 
Did you set any memory reservations on the VM? 
If you're running the Free Hypervisor ESXi then there is a 32GB PHYSICAL RAM limit.

Comment: The Host has 32GB.  I ended up increasing the allocation to the 16, 8, 8, but dropping the reservation to half that so I could use a smaller swap file.  For its intended use, even the 8GB of ram allocated should be over kill.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't have to set reservations. It is better not to. A reservation is a guarantee for PHYSICAL RAM of the host. When you have a 8GB VM, the host will only power on the VM when there is 8GB RAM free, regardless of the VM will actually use the physical RAM. On my blog GabesVirtualWorld you'll find some more info on RAM, reservations and Memory overcommit.